# Make Strong etag for content

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to build strong etag for my content you can check it in the image.[image: I want Strnong etag for my site how to do it.] open image in new tab to view it large..

Comment: Wikipedia says that etag with W/...... is weak so i thought let me do little bit better...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Answer (score 1):

You use a strong hashing algorithm like md5 or sha-1 on the file's content.

There is an explanation of the difference between weak and strong etags in the HTTP spec here:

[13.3.3 Weak and Strong Validators](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3)